# IPrincipal property is null when accessed from ASP.NET MVC controller constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iprincipal

The following sample code throws `NullReferenceException` with message `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`. The error refers to the `User` property which is `null`.

**Base controller**

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            return User.Identity.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

**Home controller**

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    private string username { get; set; }

    public HomeController()
    {
        username = UserName;
    }
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.UserName = username;
        return View();
    }
}
```

On the other hand, if the `UserName` property is accessed directly inside the action then it works fine. So, the code works if it is changed to:

**Home controller**

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.UserName = this.UserName;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Any ideas why?

**UPDATE:**

So, the real problem is the HttpContext is unavailable during the construction of the controller. I really wonder why? Any explanation? Plus, what if I need to use constructor DI to instantiate a dependency class which in turn needs to know the currently logged in user, for example:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    private IMyService service;

    public HomeController(IMyService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
        this.service.UserName = UserName;
    }

    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // use service here ...
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: The `User` property of the `Controller` class is probably not yet set when the constructor is run, but when `Index()` is called it has been set.

Comment: Any idea or documentation link as to why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have access to the HttpContext in the constructor. If you wanted a single place to add such retrieval logic you could do it in one of these ways.

---

### Call Base Controller directly

Access `UserName` property from your base controller, there is no need to reset this as a property or field on the derived controller.

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.UserName = UserName;
        return View();
    }
}
```

---

### Hook into OnActionExecuting instead of the ctor

Set the value in [Controller.OnActionExecuting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493080(v=vs.100).aspx) instead of the constructor as you have access to the HttpContext at this point. Add an `override` to the method to do this.

---

### Extension method

Add a method extension instead. I prefer this approach because I do not like controller inheritence, just inherit from the standard Mvc controller instead.

```
public static class ControllerExtension {
  public static string UserName(this Controller controller) {
    return controller.User.Identity.Name;
  }
}
```

And your code becomes

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.UserName = this.UserName();
        return View();
    }
}
```

---

## Edit

> ... where constructor DI is used to instantiate a parameter which in turn has a UserName property that needs to be set...

You would want to inject the `HttpContextBase` instance into your service and have it retrieve the authenticated user name that way. What you do not want is that the `Controller` instance needs to provide the user name to the service as this creates tightly coupled code and breaks SoC (Separation of Concerns).

```
class MyService : IMyService
{
    public string UserName {get;}
    // inject HttpContextBase
    public MyService(HttpContextBase context){
        this.UserName = context.User.Identity.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternatives. True, resetting the UserName property in the code I provided does not make much sense and is only for demonstration purposes. FWIW, I have updated the original question to showcase the real scenario where constructor DI is used to instantiate a parameter which in turn has a UserName property that needs to be set. The `service` is then used in many actions. How would you have tackled with such a case? @Igor

Comment: @dpant - you would want to inject the `HttpContextBase` into your service and have it retrieve the authenticated user name that way. The controller should not be providing it as it breaks SOC. See my update above for an illustration.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. I just had it tested with StructureMap and it works fine. FWIW, here is the DI registration for `HttpContextBase`: `For<HttpContextBase>().Use(() => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));`

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't have `HttpContext` in the constructor. The User property is not assigned until after the Controller is instantiated.

Try using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User` there.